# Search a pattern and replace it with regex in database

Tags: regex, database, regex-group, regexp-replace

In a database, I am trying to extract data and replace it with a different code.

The data looks like this (single line), it is ordered in sets of one (a.jpg) up to 8 (h.jpg). a, ab, abc, abcd, abcde, abcdef, abcdefg, abcdefgh.

```
[team url=\"//SITEURL/images/year/month/IMAGENAMEa.jpg\" style=\"meta_overlaid\" name=\"NAME 1\"]
[team url=\"//SITEURL/images/year/month/IMAGENAMEb.jpg\" style=\"meta_overlaid\" name=\"NAME 2\"]
[team url=\"//SITEURL/images/year/month/IMAGENAMEc.jpg\" style=\"meta_overlaid\" name=\"NAME 3\"]
[team url=\"//SITEURL/images/year/month/IMAGENAMEd.jpg\" style=\"meta_overlaid\" name=\"NAME 4\"]
[team url=\"//SITEURL/images/year/month/IMAGENAMEe.jpg\" style=\"meta_overlaid\" name=\"NAME 5\"]
[team url=\"//SITEURL/images/year/month/IMAGENAMEf.jpg\" style=\"meta_overlaid\" name=\"NAME 6\"]
[team url=\"//SITEURL/images/year/month/IMAGENAMEg.jpg\" style=\"meta_overlaid\" name=\"NAME 7\"]
[team url=\"//SITEURL/images/year/month/IMAGENAMEh.jpg\" style=\"meta_overlaid\" name=\"NAME 8\"]
```

With this, I was able to select a single block, thus group 1 and 3 is the required data.

```
\[team url=\\"(.+?)\\"(.+?)name=\\"(.+?)\\"(.*?)\]
```

If I wanted an abc pattern, extract data and replace it, the next one worked, but not if I needed abcd, abcde,... to abcdefgh.

Here, groups 1,3,5,7,9 and 11 are my required data.

```
\[team url=\\"(.+?)a\.jpg\\"(.+?)name=\\"(.+?)\\"(.*?)\]\[team url=\\"(.+?)b\.jpg\\"(.+?)name=\\"(.+?)\\"(.*?)\]\[team url=\\"(.+?)c\.jpg\\"(.+?)name=\\"(.+?)\\"(.*?)\]
```

I thought I could create a similar set for the other groups, but there seems to be a limit and Atom and Sublime Text stop searching.

There has to be a better way to search, group and extract, but I am lost.

Hope I was able to explain myself, thank you for your time and suggestions.

Comment: Why do you want to chain the first single short pattern with the groups that you want into a long repetitive pattern?

Comment: Hello, I am replacing tables inside posts, and there are over 1000 posts to modify. I tried modifying in parts, but it was a mess.

Answer (score 0):

In Sublime Text, you have no limit for groups.

If you need backreferences after the ninth one, use `${10}`, `${11}`, etc.

Comment: Would you mind sharing an example? I refined the groups only to match my needs, then stacked the regex one by one, both Sublime Text and Atom stop after the fifth one. Thanks.

Comment: @myuption Try the `a1b2c3d4e5f6g7h8i9j0` string, with regex set to `([[:alpha:]])(\d)([[:alpha:]])(\d)([[:alpha:]])(\d)([[:alpha:]])(\d)([[:alpha:]])(\d)([[:alpha:]])(\d)([[:alpha:]])(\d)([[:alpha:]])(\d)([[:alpha:]])(\d)([[:alpha:]])(\d)` and replacement to `$1-$3-$5-$7-$9-${11}`, the results will be `a-b-c-d-e-f`.

Comment: Thank you, I will give it a try.